# Bash case syntax - meaning of "-@"

Tags: svn, bash

I'm not familiar with the semantics of the "-@" in the bash script snippet below, which is from /etc/bash_completion.d/subversion. I'm trying to understand why bash reports "syntax error near unexpected token '(' on this line, I have two questions:

1. What is "-@()" expected to do here?
2. Why might bash be unhappy with this statement?

   ```
   case $prev in
                   # other cases omitted
       -@(F|-file|-targets))
           _filedir
           return 0;
           ;;
                   # other cases omitted
           esac
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The '@(...)' here is part of Bash's [pattern matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) syntax. It's an "or", it simply matches one of the listed patterns, separated by pipe characters.

The initial dash has simply been factored out of the expression; "-@(a|b|c)" is the same as "@(-a|-b|-c)", but shorter.

As pointed out by a commenter (thanks!) this requires Bash's `extglob` enabled to work. This is done like so:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

You can check if you already have it enabled like this:

```
shopt extglob
```

Comment: I'm guessing "-@(F|-file|-targets)" is equivalent to "-F|--file|--targets" (where '|' means "or"), but I haven't been able to confirm from documentation.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching See the bottom of the section where `extglob` is mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer to the second part of my question, which is that in order for the "@(...)" to be enabled, the "extglob" shell option needs to be on.  Executing:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

before executing the script eliminates the error.

Answer (score 0):

The "@" is a pattern that means "match one and only one". And you seem to have an extra closing paren in your code example, which is either a typo or your syntax error.

Comment: Isn't the closing paren part of the case syntax? See here, for instance: <http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-case-53>.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely a guess, as I'm not familiar with all of the bash syntax, but I think it should be more like:

```
@(-F|-file|-targets))
```

...which makes sense given the other answers here - @() matches one of the command arguments, and the extra `)` is part of the case structure.   I just think the dash is in the wrong place.

Comment: See Lance Richardson's comment on unwind's answer.